# TextFormField with icon suffix: how to prevent text from aligning to space?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Initial behavior:
Image with which I managed to reproduce.

[image]

```
 TextFormField(
                    maxLines: null,
                    maxLength: 2000,
                    decoration:  const InputDecoration(                 
                      suffix: Icon(Icons.paste_outlined,),
                    ),
                   ),
```

What I would like:

[image: What I would like. 01]
[What I would like. 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfC0R.jpg)

I don't know if it was clear but what I really needed is for only the first line to be occupied at the end of it by the icon.

Comment: Do you want to remove the padding from the Icon?

Comment: I actually wanted TextFormField to wrap the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to wrap the text around the icon because [if it exists the width of the text is reduced](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart#L937-L947) like padding.

But it's possible to draw a border around it using [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) like the designed one in the screenshot below. Check out also the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=00b2f7543c96b5e1bb70bd63312d8295).

[image: Screenshot]

[minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) source code:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(64.0),
        child: Center(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: MyCustomPainter(),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: TextFormField(
                maxLines: 10,
                maxLength: 2000,
                minLines: 10,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 8),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  suffix: Icon(
                    Icons.paste_outlined,
                    size: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 20, 0);
    path.arcTo(Rect.fromLTWH(size.width - 20, 8, 16, 16), -pi, -pi / 2, false);
    path.arcTo(
        Rect.fromLTWH(size.width - 16, 24, 16, 16), -pi / 2, pi / 2, false);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 12);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 12);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```